# Creating a data frame that contains a dictionary of lists as one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working with a defined dataframe for a project that is not giving me the output. One of the columns for the data frame contains a dictionary of lists the should present in the table as grouped entries but it seems like it's being read is individual items. What could I be missing?

**The following is the data from the dataframe:**

```
pets = pd.DataFrame({'sex': np.array(['M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M']),
                   'age': np.array([21, 45, 23, 56, 47, 70, 34, 30, 19, 62]),
                   'pets': np.array([['cat', 'dog'],
                                    ['hamster'],
                                    ['cat', 'gerbil'],
                                    ['fish', 'hamster', 'gerbil'],
                                    ['cat'],
                                    ['dog'],
                                    ['dog'],
                                    ['cat'],
                                    ['rabbit', 'cat'],
                                    ['dog']])})`
```

**When I try to create the data frame I get the following error:**
`

```
Cell In[4], line 3
      1 pets = pd.DataFrame({'sex': np.array(['M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M']),
      2                    'age': np.array([21, 45, 23, 56, 47, 70, 34, 30, 19, 62]),
----> 3                    'pets':np.array([['cat', 'dog'],
      4                                     ['hamster'],
      5                                     ['cat', 'gerbil'],
      6                                     ['fish', 'hamster', 'gerbil'],
      7                                     ['cat'],
      8                                     ['dog'],
      9                                     ['dog'],
     10                                     ['cat'],
     11                                     ['rabbit', 'cat'],
     12                                     ['dog']])})
```

``
**ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (10,) + inhomogeneous part.**

It should present me with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    sex age pets
0   M   21  [cat, dog]
1   M   45  [hamster]
2   F   23  [cat, gerbil]
3   M   56  [fish, hamster, gerbil]
4   F   47  [cat]
5   F   70  [dog]
6   F   34  [dog]
7   M   30  [cat]
8   F   19  [rabbit, cat]
9   M   62  [dog]
```

**What could I be missing?**

Answer (score 0):

Your list of list is not equal length, `np.array` couldn't handle it. You actually don't need `np.array`

```py
pets = pd.DataFrame({'sex': np.array(['M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M']),
                   'age': np.array([21, 45, 23, 56, 47, 70, 34, 30, 19, 62]),
                   'pets': [['cat', 'dog'],
                            ['hamster'],
                            ['cat', 'gerbil'],
                            ['fish', 'hamster', 'gerbil'],
                            ['cat'],
                            ['dog'],
                            ['dog'],
                            ['cat'],
                            ['rabbit', 'cat'],
                            ['dog']]})
```

```
print(pets)

  sex  age                     pets
0   M   21               [cat, dog]
1   M   45                [hamster]
2   F   23            [cat, gerbil]
3   M   56  [fish, hamster, gerbil]
4   F   47                    [cat]
5   F   70                    [dog]
6   F   34                    [dog]
7   M   30                    [cat]
8   F   19            [rabbit, cat]
9   M   62                    [dog]
```